# Define multiple auth routes with omniauth

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, devise, omniauth

I'm versioning my rails app and I want to be able to authenticate an user with 2 different routes :

```
get 'v1/auth/:provider' => 'The omniauth method containing the appropriate callback'
get 'v1/auth/:provider/callback => 'v1/sessions#create'

get 'v2/auth/:provider' => 'The omniauth method containing the appropriate callback'
get 'v2/auth/:provider/callback => 'v2/sessions#create'
```

Is it possible to "hack" the *prefix_path* attributes so I can generate both routes ?

Comment: For future reference, this was also asked here: https://github.com/omniauth/omniauth/issues/771